# Call intent in wifi direct

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I want to create an android application that opens an intent using Wifi Direct, I got this code from this [link](https://github.com/ahmontero/wifi-direct-demo) but I don't know where to put my code (calling the the application).

I tried putting in showDetails Method in WifiDirectActivity.java:

```
@Override
public void showDetails(WifiP2pDevice device) {
    DeviceDetailFragment fragment = (DeviceDetailFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_detail);
    fragment.showDetails(device);
    // Perform action on click
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.lockscreen");
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

But still nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

look into the sample code in the SDK folder and refer to the following link

http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html